# What is the difference between Array and object[] in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays

I was about to use `Enum.GetValues()` as normal, and started wondering why it returns a `System.Array` instead of `object[]`. Is it something to do with the `ComVisible` attribute?

This led to the question, what is the difference between `Array` and `object[]`, if any?

I know `Array` can be used for static methods whilst `T[]` cannot but is there a difference for instances? They seem to have the same instance methods/properties.

If there is no difference, why does `Enum.GetValues()` return `Array` instead of `object[]`?

Comment: That is just the declaration, valid because Array is the base type of any array.  You actually get an T[] back, where T is the enum type.   .NET 1.x did not yet have generics.

Comment: ´Enum.GetValues´ is from before the age of generics. It's easy to write a generic wrapper for it that returns the correct type.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I was about to use `Enum.GetValues()` as normal, and started wondering why it returns a `System.Array` instead of `object[]`.

Because `object[]` would box all the values.  What we want is an array of the values themselves, not their boxed versions.

The only way to represent that *generically* in pre-generics C# is `Array`.  Remember, that API was in the first version of the CLR, which lacked generics.

There are a number of better possible designs in a world with generics.

Frankly, there are better designs in a world without generics too. Two that immediately come to mind are: (1) This could have been an instance method on `Type`, (2) the C# compiler could have generated a `public static MyEnum[] GetValues()` method on every enum type.

> Is it something to do with the ComVisible attribute?

Not to my knowledge.

> What is the difference between `Array` and `object[]`, if any?

I don't know how to answer "what's the difference" questions.  If I asked you "what's the difference between a giraffe and a mammal?" how would you answer it? It's a bizarre question.

`Array` is the base class of `object[]` is the best I can tell you.

> I know `Array` can be used for static methods whilst `T[]` cannot but is there a difference for instances?

I don't understand this question either. Can you give an example of what you mean by "can be used for static methods"?

Perhaps what you mean is the oddity that *usually* you can access the static members of a type from a derived type, but you cannot with array types?  That is, you can say:

```
class B { public static void M() {} } 
class D : B {}
...
B.M();
D.M(); // Same thing
```

And this works:

```
Array.Sort(whatever);
```

But this does not work:

```
int[].Sort(whatever);
```

That's an oddity of how C# processes member access operators, but it's an oddity that hurts nothing because if you're typing `int[].Sort()` odds are pretty good you're doing something wrong.

Either way, I don't see what it has to do with your question. Can you clarify the question?

> If there is no difference, why does Enum.GetValues() return Array instead of object[]?

This question is incoherent. If you told me that "The White House" and "1600 Pennsylvania Avenue" were the same address, and I then said "well, if there's no difference, then why does President Trump live at The White House instead of 1600 Pennsylvania Avenue?" how would you answer my crazy question?  *If there's no difference then there's no difference, so why does it matter?*

In this case, the question is based on a false premise, as `object[]` and `Array` *are* different.  But the question as it stands cannot be answered.

Comment: *Array is the base class of object[] is the best I can tell you.* Thanks for this line. I always thought `[]` was core to the framework and `Array` used `object[]` underneath.

Comment: @TyCobb: Arrays are surprisingly complicated in the CLR; there are features in the CLR array type system that C# does not surface. For example, the CLR lets you define an array type like `int[10..20]`, that is, a one-dimensional array of ints with lower bound index 10 and upper bound index 20, *in the type system itself*, not just at runtime. C# does not support such types, obviously.

Comment: @TyCobb: But yes, `Array` is simply a base type of all array types, just as `Delegate` is a base type of all delegate types, `Enum` is a base type of all enum types, and `ValueType` is a base type of all value types.  Oddly enough, `Nullable`, the non-generic version, is *not* the base type of all nullable types.

Comment: There's a lot of extra information here but the basic answer seems to be that `Array` is the base class for `object[]` (and all `T[]`). I was thinking that `object[]` was the base class for all `T[]`s but now I see that that's not right. And the return type of `Enum.GetValues()` isn't `EnumType[]` because generics didn't exist back then. Also, not sure why it's so difficult for you to answer the giraffe/mammal question, a giraffe is a specific species while a mammal is any species in the mammal group.

Comment: @GustyAbra: No, absolutely *a giraffe* is not a *species*. *Giraffa camelopardalis* is a *species*.  A giraffe is a giraffe!  What's the difference between *the set of all giraffes* and *the set of all mammals*?  What's the difference between *the abstract concept of giraffeness* and *the abstract concept of mammalness*?  Do those two questions have the same, or different answers? Now perhaps you begin to see why the "what's the difference" question is subtle.

Comment: @GustyAbra: `object[]` is not the *base type* of any type at all; all *base types* are class types in C#, but `object[]` is an *array type*.  Note that *all single-dimensional array types with reference types for their element type are convertible to `object[]`* via *unsafe array covariance*. It's a terrible feature.

Comment: @EricLippert it's easy to find code of `Array` class - [link](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/array.cs,156e066ecc4ccedf) But where I can find code of `T[]` e.g. `object[]` ?