# Different ways of declaring arrays

Tags: vb.net

Is there any difference in the two methods of declaring an array (see below code).

In the first method, I have declared the field `nos` as an `Array Class` type. Then I use it to point towards the memory space allocated for any type of array with 5 elements. **Is this understanding correct?**

Can a similar understanding not be applied to the second case also? That is because `numbers` has bee declared as `numbers()`, it becomes  field of array type and thus can point towards any array that is being created. **If that is so then is there any difference in these two ways of declaring the arrays**??

```
        Dim nos As Array
        'Console.WriteLine(nos.GetType()) '>> Error: Object not set to reference
        nos = New Integer(4) {}
        Console.WriteLine(nos.GetType()) ' System.Int32[]

        Dim numbers = New Integer(4) {}
        Dim digits() = New Integer(4) {}
        Console.WriteLine(numbers.GetType()) ' System.Int32[]
        Console.WriteLine(digits.GetType())  ' System.Int32[]

        Dim myArray(4) As Object
        Console.WriteLine(myArray.GetType()) 'System.Object[]
```

[image: Breakpoint Analysis]

Comment: Not super familiar with VB.NET, but I would think the first declaration gets you an array of `object`, which incurs boxing and wouldn't be type-safe. The latter declaration gets you an array of int32 values, which does not incur boxing and is type-safe (you can only put int32 values in it)

Comment: Whether the parentheses are making a difference probably depends on how much type inference was built into the VB.NET compiler, and how much of the syntax is inherited from Classic VB. Do you get the same runtime type with and without them?

Comment: @MathieuGuindon my observation on your first comment: I have updated my code in the question. And as you see I cannot check the type of `nos` till this object is set to a reference. Once `nos` is set to a reference, `GetType` returns the type of whatever `nos` is pointing to - in this case System.Int32[] - an interger array. My point is that since I am not able to check the type of `nos` before making it point to something, I cannot check whether `nos` is of `OBJECT` type

Comment: You can still place a breakpoint on the assignment and inspect locals in the debugger to see what's there :)

Comment: @MathieuGuindon The second point that you made --> I checked and saw that the brackets that is `()` after `digits` is  not really making a difference. When `GetType` is used, it returns `System.Int32[]` for both `numbers`  and `digits()`

Comment: As you can see...just did the breakpoint analysis. The type of `nos` is being shown as `System.Array` and not as `System.Object[]` --> have updated the code to show what Get type returns when returning the type of an object array. So i guess System.Array and System.Object[] are not the same thing....am I right??

Comment: Indeed they are not. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/49658110/1188513

Comment: Eric's answer glosses over another important distinction in .NET, which is that one-dimensional arrays are "special" and get turned into a different type internally.  I believe that `System.Array` is the general type which can have multiple rank and can have arbitrary bounds (although the ability to have arbitrary bounds was unfortunately stripped from VB when it moved from VBA to .NET), whereas `System.Object[]` is specifically a one-dimensional vector which has a fixed lower bound of 0 in all cases.

Comment: I believe this will happen with non-object types as well.  I ran into this peculiarity at one point when I was trying to write something that acted like classic VB for indexing, and I found that my one-dimensional arrays with a lower bound of 1 didn't work with the rest of .NET the way I expected.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon re type inference in VB, as far as I know, it's on par with type inference in C#.